# concatenating a function and a string

Tags: php, concatenation

I have this statically:

```
define( 'PLUGIN_BASENAME', 'new-plugin/new-plugin.php' );
```

And `get_option('plmn-plugin-field')` will give a dynamic name. e.g. if it gives `abcd`, this should be:

```
 define( 'PLUGIN_BASENAME', 'abcd/abcd.php' );
```

And this is not working:

```
 define( 'PLUGIN_BASENAME', 'get_option('plmn-plugin-field')/get_option('plmn-plugin-field').php' );
```

How can i make it working?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
define( 'PLUGIN_BASENAME', get_option('plmn-plugin-field').'/'.get_option('plmn-plugin-field').'.php' );
```

Note:- function inside single quote will not execute in your case.Also you need to concatenate `/ and .php` with your functions.

***A demo example***:- https://eval.in/859990

Answer (score 2):

A function cannot be used inside a string. You need to call it, and concat the separator and extension, as such

```
define('PLUGIN_BASENAME', get_option('plmn-plugin-field').'/'.get_option('plmn-plugin-field').'.php');
```

If you take a closer look at the quoting, you'll notice that the arguments to each function is quoted, and that the separator `/` and extension `.php` is concatted